# xslt concat value of array

Tags: xslt, saxon

I'd like to apply template in which specified element contains value of array prefixed with some constant.

```
<xsl:variable name="coreTables"
              select="('TAB1', 'TAB2')" />
<xsl:template match="node()[not(self::*)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="databaseChangeLog">
    <xsl:comment> CORE TABLES </xsl:comment>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="changeSet[createTable/@tableName=$coreTables]"/>
    <xsl:comment> CORE SEQUENCES </xsl:comment>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="changeSet[createSequence/@sequenceName='SEQ_'[$coreTables]]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

this is sample xml:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                   http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.6.xsd
                   http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog">

    <changeSet id="1" author="a">
        <createTable tableName="TAB1">
            <column></column>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="1-1" author="a">
        <createSequence sequenceName="SEQ_TAB1" />
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet id="4" author="A">
        <createTable tableName="TAB4">
            <column></column>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

So with with last `apply-templates` I'd like to match all nodes of `createSequence` where attribute `sequenceName` is `SEQ_`+`value of some coreTables`. But I don't know how to write this select or if it's even possible like this.

I'm using xslt 2 and saxon 9.8he.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But can you edit your question to show a sample of your input XML? Thank you!

Comment: sorry forgot about that. ...sample added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a number of ways you could do this. Here's a couple...

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
     select="changeSet[createSequence/@sequenceName = (for $i in $coreTables return concat('SEQ_', $i))]"/>

<xsl:apply-templates 
     select="changeSet[createSequence[starts-with(@sequenceName, 'SEQ_') and substring-after(@sequenceName, 'SEQ_') = $coreTables]]"/>
```